# Comprobacion entre textbox

Tags: c#

Tengo un `MaskedTextBox`y un `TextBox`, quiero es validar entre uno y otro cuando el usuario introduzca un dato.

Lo que quiero es que el usuario le introduzca los datos a uno de los dos controles, de no hacerlo que le marque un `ErrorProvider`.

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so]! Te recomiendo que hagas el [tour] y así ganar tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/84/informed). Lee [ask] y [¿sobre qué temas puedo preguntar aquí?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) para aprender a realizar una buena pregunta

Comment: ¿y cuál es el problema que tenes?

Comment: la maskedtextbox y el textbox al ponerle el operador logico | or me dice que no se puede convertir de string a bool. y no quiero hacerlo para un solo textbox ya que necesito validar uno de los dos, si la condicion se cumple entre uno de los dos que me deje guardar los datos

Comment: Y como haces esa comparacion?

Comment: private void CamposObligatorios()
        {
            if (mktCedula.Text == "" | txtPasaporte.Text == "")
            {
               
                
            }
            else
            {
                errorCampos.Clear();
            }

Answer (score 0):

Bueno si lo que quieres es utilizar esa parte esta seria la solución:

```
 if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPrueba.Text) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtbPrueba.Text))
            {
               if(string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPrueba.Text))
               {
                   ErrorDatos.SetError(txtPrueba, "Dato incorrecto");
               }
               else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtbPrueba.Text))
               {
                   ErrorDatos.SetError(mtbPrueba, "Dato incorrecto");
               }
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorDatos.Clear();
            }
```

Pero te recomendaria utilizarlo de la siguiente manera ya que es mejor

```
if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(txtPrueba.Text))
            {
                ErrorDatos.SetError(txtPrueba, "Dato incorrecto");
            }
            else if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(mtbPrueba.Text))
            {
                ErrorDatos.SetError(mtbPrueba, "Dato incorrecto");
            }
            else
            {
                ErrorDatos.Clear();
            }
```

Comment: Muchisimas gracias!!